# Finding Bayes risk

Tags: statistics

I have that $f(x;\theta)=\frac{e^{-x}x^\theta}{\theta!}, x>0$ and $\pi(\theta)=(1-\alpha)\alpha^\theta, \theta=0,1,2,...$ with $0<\alpha<1$ where $\alpha$ is a known hyperparameter.

I've found the posterior distribution of $\theta$ is a Poisson distribution with mean $\alpha x$. Given the loss function $$L(d,\theta)=\frac{(\theta + 1-d)^2}{\theta + 1}, d>0,$$ I've found the expected posterior loss is maximised when $$d(x)=\frac{1}{E_{\theta|X}\left(\frac{1}{\theta + 1}\right)} = \frac{\alpha x}{1-e^{-\alpha x}}.$$ (I think my $d(x)$ is correct but I could be wrong)

Now I need to show that the Bayes risk of the estimator is $$1-(1-\alpha)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-\alpha x}}dx.$$

I know that the risk is $R(d,\theta)=E_{f(x;\theta)}(L(d,\theta))$ and the bayes risk is $r(\pi,d)=E_{\pi(\theta)}(R(d,\theta))$ but how can I actually calculate these? I don't know what to do with the $d^2$ term in the loss.